# Rotate multiple objects around local origin

Tags: transforms, origin, transform-orientation

[image]

I am trying to rotate the cubes around their local origin and I have set Transformation orientation (top of viewfinder) on local as well. To my basic knowledge they should rotate separately now.. but they don't. Although you see the Z lines separate, they still rotate around the beginning of the black dotted line, the center of both masses.

Comment: 'Local' refers to the _orientation_ of the axes of rotation. The 'Pivot' next door, to the right, (currently 'Bounding Box Center'), sets the _location(s)_ of the axes. Set that to 'Individual Origins'.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks! And for the explanation as well.